# Live wallpaper not receiving ACTION_MOVE events?

Tags: android, wallpaper, touch-event

I've found that my live wallpaper doesn't seem to receive ACTION_MOVE events when the CPU is maxed out. It does, however, still receive the ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP events.

I've set up a minimal eclipse project to demonstrate. Menu->Configure allows you toggle a frame rate cap.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/m7v0czmovtatuu1/TouchTest.zip

Has anyone else encountered this, or have an explanation as to why?

Edit: I've since found that this only occurs in gingerbread. Still no solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't look at your source because the file isn't available anymore but you should try that:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        // your touch down code
                        return true;
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                        //your touch move code
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                       //your touch up code
                        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
```

Comment: Hi, this the OP with another account. Unfortunately that's not a fix as no MotionEvents of any type are received in the method at that time. Additionally, there's no return type for the onTouchEvent() method in the wallpaper service, so it's not possible to return 'true' to specify that the service will handle subsequent events like a normal touch handler. :(